# Painting over a custom control that already paints

Tags: winforms

I created several custom .NET Winform controls that inherit from UserControl. One of them, ArrowButton, shares a lot of properties with another, slightly simpler one called CustomButton. ArrowButton is essentially CustomButton but with an arrow drawn next to the text. Both of them currently add a common Button to the UserControl base and then have Paint events call functions that draw the gradiant background, customized text, and arrow graphics in the case of the ArrowButton. This works fine.

But then I started thinking it would make sense to have the ArrowButton use a CustomButton instead of the normal button so that it gets the background and text from that, and all ArrowButton would have to do is draw the arrow on top of it.

I replaced the Button in ArrowButton with CustomButton. So far so good. But when it runs, it just looks like a CustomButton and the arrow part is never being drawn. As far as I can tell, the painting code in ArrowButton is not being called. Or possibly being painted over by the CustomButton.

So is it possible to have CustomButton paint first and then ArrowButton paint on top of it in an additive fashion? And if so should I be doing so using

```
void InitializeComponent(void) 
{
this->CustmBtn = (gcnew CustomButton());
....
this->CustmBtn->Paint += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventHandler(this, &ArrowButton::ArrowBtn_Paint);
```

overriding OnPaint(), or using some other method? I'm working in C++/CLI but C# examples will probably work too.

Edit - Extra details:
I changed ArrowButton to inherit from CustomButton instead of UserControl. This definitely seems like the way to go since I get to auto-inherit all of the properties from CustomButton and it still works fine in the VStudio designer. That said, it still refuses to draw the arrow. And I confirmed (using Console::WriteLine() calls) that both the Paint event function and my OnPaint() override functions where I'm trying to do the arrow paint are never getting called at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution of my own and as far as I can tell its a good one. Feels a lot simpler then the transparency or Region clipping-based workarounds I've seen in similar questions too.

I added this to CustomButton:

```
virtual void ExtraChildDraw(Graphics^ grph) {}
```

At the end of my CustomButton paint event function I call it and pass in the PaintEventArgs->Graphics reference I had been using there. Since it uses the default version of the function in the base class, it does nothing extra.

Then in ArrowButton or any other child-class I want to make of CustomButton I override the function and do all the extra 2D painting I want to add on top of what CustomButton does. It works great and even shows up correctly in the VStudio designer.